# Error on list-colors-display

Tags: colors

When running this function:

```
M-x list-colors-display
```

I always get the following error:

```
Wrong number of arguments: #<subr max>, 0
```

If I try to use edebug in the function I get:

```
edebug-signal: Wrong number of arguments: #<subr max>, 0
```

The same happens starting emacs -q, I'm using: This is GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0, NS appkit-1504.83 Version 10.12.6 (Build 16G1408))
 of 2018-06-21

As pointed in the comments this was bug for the emacs that I installed with homebrew and --HEAD option. now with this version or < 26.1 works well:

```
This is GNU Emacs 27.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.10 Version 10.14.1 (Build 18B75))
 of 2018-12-08
```

Comment: Do you get the same error when you run Emacs without your init file (`emacs -q`)?

Comment: yes exactly the same trying with -q, I will update the question

Comment: Emacs 27 has not been released yet. In this case you can probably report this as a bug to the Emacs team.

Comment: I think the error comes from list-colors-print, which seems to have a nil at the end, and that gives you the error you see.

Comment: @JohnKitchin: Please consider posting that as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the error comes from list-colors-print, which seems to have a nil at the end, and that gives you the error you see. This doesn't seem to happen in earlier versions of emacs and is probably a bug.

Comment: As also pointed in the comments I send the bug to emacs community, then I update my emacs and it worked again

Comment: Where is list-colors-print to be found? I work with Emacs Prelude.

Comment: list-colors-display is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `facemenu.el'.

Answer (score 0):

I have a hacky fix for this for Emacs 26.3 at https://github.com/simon-katz/nomis-emacs-configuration/blob/933d6330ff642bca184671efd5df2dd2fa8a580e/emacs-installation/emacs-init-files/nomis-list-colors-print-hacks.el

It replaces the definition of `list-colors-print` to fix the bug.

EDIT:

I reported this bug at https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=50094

The fix for me (on my Mac) was:

rm $HOME/Library/Colors/Emacs.clr
After that, things worked properly.